# ¿Como puedo sacar el total de una columna?

Tags: javascript

Quiero sumar las columnas de Meta y Actual y ponerles un total de cada una 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
    $.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  url: '/client/mes/production/production/fridgeProductivity/',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
      'operationNo':1,
      'sistemDI' : $('#select2_sistema').select2('val'),
      'startDateA':startDateA,
      'endDateA': endDateA,   
      'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
  },
  success: function(cntxAjax) {

    $('#SearchBut').prop('enable', true);
    set_graphs(cntxAjax.cntxPQ, cntxAjax.cntxRQ);
    // rellenando mi tabla
    table.clear().draw()
    var sumaCumu = 0;
    cntxAjax.cntxDato.forEach(function(datos){
      var valPQ = parseInt(datos[0])
      var valRQ = parseInt(datos[1])
      var cumu = valPQ - valRQ  //La resta de meta y actual
      sumaCumu += cumu //suma de diferencia y mcumulo
      console.log(sumaCumu)
      table.row.add({
        '0': datos[0],
        '1': datos[1],
        '2': cumu,
        '3': sumaCumu,
        '4': datos[2],
      }).draw(); 
    })
  }
});
```

Lo que me interesa solo es lo que se resalta en amarillo, una sola fila, pero me da varias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si usas algún framework deberías decirlo, para que te den una respuesta basada en ese framework . Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el mismo metodo que usaste para la suma cumulativa.  Algo asi:

```js
var cntxDato = [[20,15,100],[30,23,200]];

var sumaCumu = 0;
var sumaMeta = 0;
var sumaActual = 0;

var table = [];

cntxDato.forEach(function(datos){
          // console.log(datos)
          var valPQ = parseInt(datos[0])
          var valRQ = parseInt(datos[1])
          var cumu = valPQ - valRQ  
          sumaCumu += cumu
          sumaMeta += valPQ;
          sumaActual += valRQ;
          console.log(sumaCumu)
          table.push({
            '0': datos[0],
            '1': datos[1],
            '2': cumu,
            '3': sumaCumu,
            '4': datos[2],
          });
                       
        });
        table.push({
          '0': sumaMeta,
          '1': sumaActual,
          '2': 0,
          '3': 0,
          '4': 0
        });
        console.log(table);
```

Comment: ¡Me funciono! Pero, solo quiero que me de un solo resultado que seria el total de toda una columna... si me lo suma pero por fila y se va a cumulando. y solo quiero un solo TOTAL de cada una.@alanfcm

Comment: No entiendo, el codigo solo agrega la fila con los totales al final.  Quizas estas agregando la fila dentro del `forEach`.

Comment: Necesito otra tabla con el total de Meta y Actual, pero en mi tabla me lo hace así (edite mi pregunta)

Comment: Me parece que reemplazaste `table.row.add` pero si te fijas en mi respuesta tengo dos `push` el que esta dentro del `forEach` se queda igual.  El segundo lo agregas fuera del `forEach`

Comment: ¡Tienes razón! ¡Que torpe! muchas gracias.